# Creating a clustered image from kmeans data in OpenCV

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, k-means

I am trying to create a clustered image from data being returned from the kmeans function. I try to pull out the data in a similar fashion from the OpenCV example but that seems to crash on me. After some further research I saw that someone had pulled data out by using the centers, but did nothing with that data so my trail ended there.

I have included a snippet of my code and what I am doing below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I've reverted my code back to it's original state without any test variables. Still the above error persists. I have also added some debugging information about my image below:

Image information:

- Dimensions: 2
- Image data:
- Size 0: 256
- Size 1: 256
- Elemsize 1: 12
- Elemsize 2: 4

While data is NULL I am still able to view the data if I call `cv::imshow` on it.

```
// mImage is a cv::Mat that was created from a 256 x 256 image with the depth of
// CV_32F and 3 channels
// labels is a cv::Mat that was created by converting the image into a 256 x 256
// CV_8UC1 IplImage
kmeans(mImage, 6, labels, termcrit, 3, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
float* c = new float[6];
memcpy(c, centers.ptr<float>(0), sizeof(float)*6);

// Block of code that crashes when I do "mImage.at<cv::Point2f>(i)" with the error:
/* OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (size.p[0] == 1 || 
       size.p[1] == 1) && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)(size.p[0] + size.p[1] - 1) && 
       elemSize() == (((((DataType<_Tp>::type) & ((512 - 1) << 3)) >> 3) + 1) << 
       ((((sizeof(size_t)/ 4+1)*16384|0x3a50) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::type) & 
       ((1 << 3) - 1))*2) & 3))) in unknown function, file 
       c:\opencv-2.3.0\modules\core\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 583 */

for(int i = 0; i < list.rows; i++)
{
    int clusterIdx = list.at<int>(i);
    cv::Point ipt = mImage.at<cv::Point2f>(i);
    circle( miplImage, ipt, 2, colorTab[clusterIdx], CV_FILLED, CV_AA );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the assertion error at the call to mRegion.at(). Where is mRegion defined?

Here's the equivalent snippet from the `kmeans.cpp` sample code:

```
    kmeans(points, clusterCount, labels, 
           TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0),
           3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);

    img = Scalar::all(0);

    for( i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++ )
    {
        int clusterIdx = labels.at<int>(i);
        Point ipt = points.at<Point2f>(i);
        circle( img, ipt, 2, colorTab[clusterIdx], CV_FILLED, CV_AA );
    }
```

It uses the same variable `points` for both the first argument to `kmeans` and as the source for `ipt` in the `for` loop. I think you probably want to use `mImage` in the `for` loop, not mRegion.

**Edit** So now that you've changed the code to use mImage in the `for` loop, you need to see why you are getting the assertion error. The assertion message is very cluttered by the template code so here it is from mat.hpp:

```
dims <= 2 && data && (size.p[0] == 1 || size.p[1] == 1) &&
             (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)(size.p[0] + size.p[1] - 1) &&
             elemSize() == CV_ELEM_SIZE(DataType<_Tp>::type)
```

One or more of those tests fails. If you are using an empty mImage, that would be a failure because `data` would be nil. You can't call `at` on an empty matrix. In any case, examine the properties of mImage to see which is causing the assertion error.

Comment: Sorry to omit some variables as I was just testing different techniques seeing if I could get something. mRegion is just an empty matrix with the dimensions and types as mImage. I tried with mImage and it through that error so I tried with an empty matrix and got the same error.

Comment: So in that case do I have to convert my 256x256 image into an array of 65536x1?

Comment: No, the 256x256 is ok. That's the `dims <= 2` test. You are probably failing because `data` is nil or `i` is greater than the number of points. Try adding `cout << "data: " << mImage.data << endl;` before the `for` loop.

Comment: It seems that I lose my data when I try to convert my matrix. Now I have to find out how to hold onto the data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It turns out you can't run kmeans directly on an image. It needs to be run on an n-row by 1-column matrix that contains coordinates. In this case, they are 2D coordinates. I haven't done this myself, but perhaps you can run a threshold on your input image then populate a matrix with the dimensions of the pixels above the threshold.